# How can I apply a custom scalar function elementwise to a matrix in math.js?

Tags: javascript, function, matrix, elementwise-operations, mathjs

Consider the matrix m:

```
let m = [ [ 1 , 2 ] , [ 3 , 4 ] ]
```

Apply the exponentiation function to m:

```
let mexp = math.exp(m)
```

Now `JSON.stringify(mexp)` outputs:

```
"[[2.718281828459045,7.38905609893065],[20.085536923187668,54.598150033144236]]"
```

So the built in exponentiation function was applied elementwise to the matrix and the result is a matrix.

Let's say I have a custom scalar function `sigmoid`:

```
let sigmoid = x => 1 / ( 1 + Math.exp(-x) )
```

Now I would like to apply `sigmoid` elementwise to the matrix as if it was a math.js built in function:

```
math.sigmoid(m)
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could simply use `math.map`, and customize sigmoid to work with `map`

```
math.map(m, sigmoid)
```

more here http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/map.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used math.map(m,sigmoid) and it worked.